# JS fullscreenchange on mobile Safari for Vimeo

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, fullscreen, vimeo-api

I am facing a problem with catching fullscreen event from Vimeo iframe movie (created by Vimeo JS api) in mobile Safari (iPhone 6s). Currently I am using

```
$(document).on(
    'webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange',
    function(e){
        console.log("fullscreen event",e);
    }
);
```

And the above code is fine for Chrome (both desktop and mobile), desktop Safari and others, but not for mobile Safari.
Is there a way to fix this event? Do you know any workarounds for Vimeo? window.innerHeight and window.screen doesn't change.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?